# Duplicate entries are made on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, button, html-lists

I am trying to create a simple functionality where I have one text box and a dropdown menu which contains positive and negative term. When I write for example good in textbox and select positive from drop down the word good should be added to positive list. It is working I am getting duplicate entries and also I need to sort the list as I keep adding values. Please help me out;
here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var flag = true;
if (x == null || x == "") {
alert("Name must be filled out");
flag = false;
        }
if (x.length > 50) {
alert("Term should not be longer than 50");
flag = false;
}
return flag;
    }
function myFunction() {
var node = document.createElement("LI");
var answer = document.getElementById("selectMe").value;
var textboxvalue = document.getElementById("t1").value;
if (answer == "positive") {
var textnode = document.createTextNode(textboxvalue);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("Positive").appendChild(node);
        } 
else if (answer == "negative") {
var textnode = document.createTextNode(textboxvalue);
node.appendChild(textnode);
document.getElementById("negative").appendChild(node);
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h3> <strong> Javascript Test </strong></h3>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<label>Term: </label>
</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="fname" id="t1"> </td>
</tr>
<br/>
<tr>
<td>
<label> Type:</label>
</td>
<td>
<select name="title" required id="selectMe">
<option value="">Choose:</option>
<option value="positive">Positive</option>
<option value="negative">Negative</option>
</select>
</select>
</td>
<tr>                
<td>
<button onclick="myFunction()"> Onclick </button>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<fieldset>
<legend>See Result in this Section:</legend>
<label> Positive </label>
<ul id="Positive">
</ul>
<label> Negative </label>
<ul id="negative">
</ul>
</fieldset>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#myForm").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if (validateForm()) {
myFunction();enter code here
}
});
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please share the HTML code as well to debug easily

Comment: I have updated can you please check it and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve expected result, please use below option

```
function myFunction() {
  var node = document.createElement("LI");
  var answer = document.getElementById("selectMe").value;
  var textboxvalue = document.getElementById("t1").value;
  if (answer == "positive") {
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(textboxvalue);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    var p = document.getElementById("Positive").childNodes; // child Nodes of positive
    if (p[1]) {
      var preValue = p[1].innerHTML;
      if (preValue > textboxvalue) { // compare with previous positive value to insertbefore or append
        document.getElementById("Positive").insertBefore(node, p[1]);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("Positive").appendChild(node);
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("Positive").appendChild(node);
    }
  } else if (answer == "negative") {
    var c = document.getElementById("negative").childNodes; // child Nodes of negative
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(textboxvalue);
    node.appendChild(textnode);

    if (c[1]) {
      var preValue = c[1].innerHTML;
      if (preValue > textboxvalue) { // compare with previous negative value to insertbefore or append
        document.getElementById("negative").insertBefore(node, c[1]);
      } else {
        document.getElementById("negative").appendChild(node);
      }
    } else {
      document.getElementById("negative").appendChild(node);
    }
  }

  //document.body.appendChild(node);
}
```

http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/RRKpvm

Comment: To make it work in my local, i have removed form tag to avoid submitting form... You can replace the function -myFunction() with my code..Hope this works for you :)

Comment: @sai thank you so much. I have one question you are just comparing first index with the newly entered value. eg if I enter apple then cat it should be apple cat bt just after cat if i enter bag then it should be apple bag cat but it shows apple cat bag. I mean in such case we need to loop through the entire array till its length correct?

Comment: yes we need to loop it render previous LI elements ..which makes you to create more conditions . as loop the entire array sort that array by Array.sort

Comment: @sai can you give me a rough idea? I am actually new with the functions you used for this function

Comment: @shive, could you please create new question , as it is answered, i will check and update that with answer :)

Comment: @shiva , please provide the question link here

Comment: @sai http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022156/sorting-logic-for-arranging-a-list